# Can I interact with a running Python session from MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab, session

I have a Fortran library wrapped to Python (with f2py), and I want to call the library from MATLAB (2016b). Although it's possible to call the Fortran library from MATLAB using MEX files, to save some work I'm hoping it's possible to call it using the Python interface. I know that one can call Python code from MATLAB (e.g. py.calendar.isleap(2016)), but unfortunately it seems that this only gives access to standard Python libraries.

Since the library has initialization cost, I prefer to initialize once and maintain a *running* Python session, and write MATLAB wrappers for library initialization and the library routines I wish to call. I'm not entirely sure how the MATLAB and Python sessions can best communicate, but I guess writing and reading temporary text files is a viable option.

Any suggestions for a good way to maintain an active Python session in MATLAB, and pass input to Python and output back to MATLAB?

Comment: What about using `system` (https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) to run Python?

Comment: I can do that, but is there any way to keep the same Python session running between calls? If not I'll have to initialize my library every time I want to call it.